# How can i import modules from Existing Mercurial Repository in Intellij ? (Like in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, mercurial

I m trying Intellij , I was an Eclipse user.

I create an empty project, I want to add some modules, these modules are coming  from a mercurial repository.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I want to import a  module, I can't see import from "Clone Existing Mercurial Repository", we can see this option in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: What's the question again?

Comment: How can i import modules from Existing Mercurial Repository in Intellij ? ( (Like Eclipse) @m02ph3u5

Comment: Better make this your question's title then ;)

Comment: So do you have an idea @m02ph3u5 ?

Answer (score 0):

- SELECT FILE - NEW - PROJECT FROM VERSION CONTROLE - MERCURIAL

[image]